# Better lambda to get distinct values on object hierarchy

Tags: java, lambda

We have object A type that contains an array of objects B type than contains an array of objects C type like in the example:

```
/* sample structure that ends with 4 instances of C with ids.100,200,100,200 */
private class A{
        int id;
        A(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        B[] b = new B[]{new B(10), new B(20) };
    }

    private class B{
        int id;
        B(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        C[] c = new C[]{new C(100), new C(200) };

    }

    private class C{
        int id;
        C(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return ""+id;
        }

    }
```

If we try to get all *distinct c.id* (100, 200) the first approach could be

```
HashSet<Integer> distinctIdsOfC = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (B bbb: a.b){
    for (C ccc: bbb.c){
        distinctIdsOfC.add(ccc.id);
    }
}
```

(The result is 100, 200 as expected)

And my first attepmt with lambdas

```
List<C> a6 = Arrays.asList(a.b).stream().map(jaja -> Arrays.asList(jaja.c)).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
a6.stream().map(x->x.id).distinct().forEach(System.out::println);
```

(The result is again 100, 200 as expected)

And finally the question. ***Any better alternative lambda?***

```
/* Complete source sample to test */
package test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.haz();
    }

    private void haz() {

        A a = new A(1);

        HashSet<Integer> distinctIdsOfC = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (B bbb : a.b) {
            for (C ccc : bbb.c) {
                distinctIdsOfC.add(ccc.id);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("with for-loop" + distinctIdsOfC.toString());

        System.out.println("with lambda");
        List<C> a6 = Arrays.asList(a.b).stream().map(jaja -> Arrays.asList(jaja.c)).flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        a6.stream().map(x -> x.id).distinct().forEach(System.out::println);

    }

    private class A {
        int id;

        A(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        B[] b = new B[] { new B(10), new B(20) };
    }

    private class B {
        int id;

        B(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        C[] c = new C[] { new C(100), new C(200) };

    }

    private class C {
        int id;

        C(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "" + id;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `Arrays.stream(a.b).flatMap(b -> Arrays.stream(b.c))`. But what you should really do is to stop using arrays. Use Lists instead.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not in my hand. The object structure is imposed.

Comment: Oh, and of course, use `collect(Collectors.toSet())`. Why go through a list?

Comment: Not sure why you separated your stream expression into two statements. Why not continue after the `flatMap`, and collect to a set or use distinct on the result?

Comment: I'm using 2 statements as this is my first "real" lambda excluding tutorials or books or study. No real reason for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I think we many options but:

1) Implementes equlas/hashCode in C class, and then:

```
        Arrays.stream(a.b)
            .map(s -> s.c)
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .distinct()
            .forEach(System.out::println)
```

But, if You can't add hashCode/equals:

2) Create filter method (distinct by class field):

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    Map<Object,Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return t -> seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
}
```

And then write lambdas like this:

```
        Arrays.asList(a.b).stream()
            .map(jaja -> Arrays.asList(jaja.c))
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .filter(distinctByKey(s -> s.id))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: As long as we are dealing with arrays, rather use `Arrays.stream` or `Stream.of` instead of `Arrays.asList().stream()`. Instead of `map(asList)` you can also call `flatMap` directly: `flatMap(jaja -> Arrays.stream(jaja.c))` . That way you are not creating a list, which you don't need anyhow.

Comment: Right, and next better solution `Arrays.asList(a.b).stream().map(s -> s.c).map(Arrays::stream).distinct()/..CODE.../` Thanks @Roland

Comment: beware of the `map(Arrays::stream)`... should rather be: `Arrays.stream(a.b).map(s -> s.c).flatMap(Arrays::stream).distinct().forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 0):

With all the valuable information in comments, the idea that we was looking for distinct id values, not distict objects and trying to get it simpler,
ended with the lambda.

```
    /* proposed lambda */

    System.out.println("with lambda");
    Set<Integer> a7 = Arrays.stream(a.b).flatMap(jaja-> Arrays.stream(jaja.c).map(jeje->jeje.id)).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    System.out.println("with lambda set a7");
    a7.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

That avoids intermediate non use List, avoids distinct and it's shorter and clear.

Comment: Ok, so please inline this like that: `Arrays.stream(a.b).map(s -> s.c).flatMap(Arrays::stream).map(s -> s.id).distinct().forEach(System.out::println)`. Difference between my answer and your solution is only add one .map(function), and then You have simple code, and you have distinct ids from all object C class

Comment: There is no need to use `stream()` when you only want to do `forEach(…)`. You can just do `a7.forEach(System.out::println);` But as said by Mateusz, you can just do `forEach` in the preceding stream operation without collecting into a `Set` at all.